# Deleting nodes greater than specified value from linked list

Tags: algorithm, linked-list

Given an integer value and a pointer to the head of the linked list, how to delete all the nodes from the list that are greater than the specified value?

e.g.

List :   10->34->11->19->26->55->17
value:   19
output:  10->11->17 (All the nodes greater than 19 needs to be removed)

(Edge case)

List :   10->3->17->5->2->14->7
value:   9
output:  3->5->2->7 (All the nodes greater than 9 needs to be removed)

I am not looking for the exact code but just an algorithm to solve this!

Comment: `std::list::remove_if` http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/remove

Comment: I do not need stl implementation...but i am looking for an algorithm to implement it myself!

Comment: Please explain why you are not using `std::list`?  If this is an assignment then please show what you have tried so far.

Comment: I just want to know the logic behind the implementation....
Its not that i have to implement this somewhere..... @RichardCritten

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[image]
Consider the picture here .Suppose we have to delete the node which is greater than 8 and we have `Head` Pointer pointing to head of the list.First we will take two pointers `Prev` and `temp` both points to head initially.Then through the pointer we will traverse the list and keep track the `current` and `prev` pointers in `temp` and  `Prev`.If current number is greater than 8 `Prev` will point to the next node pointed by `temp` and temp node will be deleted.By traversing all the node and following this rule you can delete the specified node of the list....
I hope you got the point........

Answer (score 4):

```
private static Node removeNodes(Node start, int x) {

if(start == null) return start;

if(start.data > x && start.next == null) return null;

//find first head node
Node cur = start;
Node prev = null;

//4,5,3,2,1,6 --- where x = 2
while(cur != null && cur.data > x) {
    prev = cur;
    cur = cur.next;
}

if(prev != null) prev.next = null;

Node newHead = cur;

while(cur.next != null) {
    if(cur.next.data > x) {
        cur.next = cur.next.next;
    } else {
        cur = cur.next;
    }
}

return newHead;
}
```

Comment: Good solution. However, in order to delete even the value that is passed(i.e. x) need to check for the conditon (cur.next.data >= x) instead of just (cur.next.data > x)

Answer (score 2):

first assign a temporary node to the start node

Then you have **three cases** in linked list..
if the  desired node at the first position then make start to be equal `start->next` and delete temp node
if it is in the middle make another node to be stopped right before temp and make the next of that node to be equal the next of temp and then `delete temp`
if it is at last position make the next of the node before it to be equal to `nullptr` and that is it.

Answer (score 0):

It can be solved using two pointers, previous and current,I guess this solution work.

```
public static ListNode removeNode(ListNode head,int value){

        //removing every element whose Node value is greter than given value
        if(head==null) { return head;}

        ListNode current=head;
        ListNode previous=new ListNode(0);
        previous.next=current;


        while(current!=null){               
            //System.out.println("current value; "+current.val);
            if(current.val>=value){
                if(current.next==null){
                    current=null;
                }
                else {
                current=current.next;}
                previous.next=current;
            }           
            else {
            previous=previous.next;
            current=current.next;
            }
        }
        return head;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void deletenodes(int x) {
    if(head == null) {
        System.out.println("list is  empty");
        return;
    }
    If(head > x) {
        head = head.next;
    }
    //check and removes the Node until the next becomes null.
    Node secondlast = head;
    Node last = head.next;
    while(secondlast.next != null) {
        if(secondlast.next.data > x) {
            secondlast.next = last.next;
    }
    secondlast = secondlast.next;
}
```

Comment: You should add explanation.

Comment: Ok I will do that